# Rendering a data-table only when the bean returns a list

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have been trying to render a rich:dataTable, but fails, when it comes to its conditional rendering.I wanted to render it only if the size of the list, the backing-bean fetches from DB, is greater than zero.

JSF-2.0, RichFaces-4 are what i use.

Comment: Post your code so we can see.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the "render" attribute of the datatable. With it you can define if the component is rendered to the client or not. So check by EL if the list is populated.

you can do something like:

```
rendered="#{not empty listObject}"
```

and all is fine.
I always implement my database query method to never return null, if the query has no result I return an empty list. This way i'm sure I never get a nullpointerexception and I prefer then to show an empty table. Because it's easer to layout the page, when you are sure the table always exist.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Don't you mean `rendered`. There's no `render` attribute for `<rich:dataTable>` in richfaces 4 http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/dataTable.html

Comment: Sorry yes, its rendered. In the moment switching from jsf to vaadin/gwt. So richfaces4 I scratched the surface not more.

Comment: Late in letting know. But the problem is solved. I wrapped the data-table in a <h:panelGrid/> and added  the rendered attribute to it. I guess when there is this problem of 'render', we can always think of wrapping it and try rendering it, instead of the component which is in the wrap.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario is I have a groupId which I rightclick on. On the context menu, I choose Display CTNs and it should then render all the CTNs of this group in a data-table. It starts with a JavaScript call, which I call once I choose "Display CTNs". It takes care of supplying the GroupId to the a4j:jsFunction.

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{ctnGrpMgmtController.ctnDetailsList}"
                                    var="ctnVar" id="ctnTable" rows="5"
                                    rendered="#{not empty ctnDetailsList}">
```

The above should be rendered after the below a4j:jsFunction executes.

```
  <a4j:jsFunction name="selectGroupForManagingCtns"
                                        action="#{ctnGrpMgmtController.loadCTNsForAGroup}"
                                        render="ctnListPanel,ctnTable">
                                        <a4j:param name="name"
                                            assignTo="#{ctnGrpMgmtController.groupId}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

I have to do an F5 to see the component "ctnTable", which is where the problem starts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the attribute name on the a4j:jsFunction is reRender instead of just render. Should fix it.